# Having trouble plotting a logarithmic equation

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I want to plot these two logarithmic equations:

1. $\log_{10}x^2 = 6$

$10^{\log_{10}x^2} = 10^6$

$x^2 = 10^6$

$x=\pm 10^3$

This is my code for trying to plot this:

```
Plot[
{Log[x^2], 6},
{x, -5, 5},
Epilog ->
  {
  Red, PointSize @ 0.015, Point[{1000, -1000, 80}]
  }
 ]
```

2. $\log_{10}(z-3) = 2$

Doing the same thing I get, $z-3=100$, so $z-103$

Similarly, my code for this is:

```
Plot[
 {Log[z - 3], 2},
 {z, -100, 100},
 Epilog ->
  {
  Red, PointSize @ 0.015, Point[{103, 80}]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: It is meaningless to state you'll plot an "equation."  Instead you plot a *function*.  That is the source of your confusion, and why your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to do the algebra by hand:

```
Solve[Log10[x^2] == 6, x]
{{x -> -1000}, {x -> 1000}}
```

Then you can plot both sides of the equation, which I think is what you are looking for:

```
Plot[{Log[10, x^2], 6}, {x, -1200, 1200}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@0.015, Point[{1000, 6}], Point[{-1000, 6}]}]
```

[image]